# What does the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ represent when $x, y, r$ are complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, research

I know this question is vague or maybe broad and subjective.

But, I am interested in studying the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ when $x,y,r$ are complex numbers.

What are a few directions that I can follow to study this equation? Is it even interesting (subjective, I know)? Are there already results for this equation?

Comment: That $z$ should be $r$ I guess

Comment: You might start by writing each of $x,y,r$ in the form $u+iv$ [different letters for each of the three complex numbers, so 6 letters in all]. Next perform the squares, then equate real and imaginary parts.

Comment: A first observation is that for every complex $x$, there are two complex $y$ that satisfy the equation (except when $x=\pm r$ in which case $y=0$): $y=\pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. But visualizing this relation in all its complex glory will require some dalliances with four dimensions.

Comment: Fermat curve might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_curve

Comment: This looks like a zero set of a homogeneous polynomial (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety#Projective_variety).

Answer (score 2):

IMO it just represents that the squares of the complex numbers $x$ and $y$ addition through parallelogram law is the same as the square of the third complex number $r$.

If you take $x=a+ib, y=c+id, r= e+if$ then after simplifying a little bit you will get

$$a^2+c^2+f^2-b^2-d^2-e^2=0$$
$$ab+cd-ef=0$$
which doesn’t indicate anything geometrical to me at least.

You can calculate the argument of $r^2$ through $x$ and $y$ which is

$$\arg(r^2)=\arctan\left(\frac{2(ab+cd)}{a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2}\right)$$